# Php - retry execution of a line

Tags: php, variables, line, handler, execute

Before to explain what i want to do, here is my code :

```
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr)
{
    if (strpos($errstr, 'Undefined variable: ') === 0)
    {
        // Get my var
        $words = explode(' ', $errstr);

        // Var is not declared before so "we create it" in global (wizard astuce ;p)
        global $route, ${$words[2]};

        // I put a content to my var
        ${$words[2]} = array('tutu' => 'toto');

        // I don't display error
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}, E_NOTICE);

// I want to display "toto" without declared my var before
echo $News['tutu'].'<br/><br/>';
echo $News['tutu'].'<br/><br/>';
```

So..., the first time $News['tutu'] doesn't works and the second time it works very well.

And what i want to do is to retry the first execution of $News['tutu'] or to get the end of my var (['tutu']) then I could get "toto".

If i can steer clear of use "substr", "open", ect... It would be perfect.

Comment: That's some really weird usage of an error handler. It will make your code really more complex to understand for anyone else.

Comment: Haha i know.The truth is to make everything with nothing ! If you prefer, if you need to call an unknow object/var/function/... without declared it before, this system find a solution for you.  (I know it's strange but I'm curious)